# domexception thrown while playing audio in Chrome

Tags: javascript, media

Hello I am getting an exception when playing audio in Chrome.

Here is my function to play the audio

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    generateAlarm();
});

function generateAlarm()
{
    alarm_1 = new Audio();
    alarm_1.src = '/Content/assets/sounds/alarm_1.mp3';
    const playPromise = alarm_1.play();

    if (playPromise !== null)
    {
        playPromise.catch(() => {
           const btn = $('#playAlarm');
           btn.click();
         });
    }
}

document.getElementById('playAlarm').addEventListener("click", handlePlayButton, false);

function handlePlayButton()
{
    if (alarm_1.paused) {
        generateAlarm();
    }
    else {
        alarm_1.pause();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the above code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: is your audio actually loading?

Comment: The audio plays when i call generateAlarm in loading event handler, but when i refresh the page i get the uncaught exception.

Comment: its probably because chrome doesn't allow you to autoplay audio/video without user interaction. If you call the function with a button, does it still happen?

Comment: I tried to do like in the code above, but still getting the same exception plus ressource unvailable exception too

Answer (score 2):

Autoplaying audio is no longer allowed because it's obnoxious and is frequently abused. You have to wait for the user to interact with the page first. You can check out this guide by google on how to use the new `AudioContext` api: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/11/web-audio-autoplay

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i could find so far was to change the chrome autoplay policies like this:

> chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy

and set it to

> No user gesture is required

i don't if it is the right way to solve the problem, but i am not getting anymore exception. I would appreciate if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: its not the right way as that only works for your browser. The code you have posted in the doc ready function is still an attempt to autoplay the sound. You are not allowed to do that